# How to solve undefined is not a function (near '...userForm.map...')?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

Im trying to render some strings , but I'm getting error, someone knows how to solve it ?

code :

```
const FormScreen = ({route}) => {
  const [userForm, setuserForm] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userForm.length > 0) {    
      console.log('userform',userForm,userForm.length); // not get inside here gives me a eror before it
      return
    }
    else{
      setuserForm(route.params.paramKey);
      console.log('TEST',userForm,'LENG',userForm.length)} // returns => TEST [] LENG 0
  },[userForm])
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>COLLECTION :</Text>     
        {userForm.length > 0 ? (       
          userForm.map((item) => (          
            <Text key={uuid.v4()}>{item.fields}</Text>
          ))
        ) : (
          <Text key={uuid.v4()}> Loading ... </Text>
        )}
{..}
```

`route.params.paramKey` is a string

`route.params.paramKey` string is = `{"objeto":"CLMobj_test","fields":["abcs","test"],"type":["Date","Text"]}`

Comment: Can you post a copy/paste of the full error message? This should be more helpful to others for gaining a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: @StaceyBurns infact this is the full error message `TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...userForm.map...')
This error is located at: {...}`

Comment: Thanks @Guilherme, have you tried using userForm && userForm.length > 0 for the condition before the userForm.map ? (instead of only userForm.length > 0)

Comment: @StaceyBurns Yeap , and the error stand still

Comment: hmm, seeing your recent edit it looks like you have a json object formatted as a string. From your example, are you attempting to map "abcs" and "test" ? What would you expect to render given the string you provided?

Comment: I just want to do an for each in the fields json , returning one after the other @StaceyBurns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `route.params.paramKey` is a string, you cannot call `map` on it directly.
If you want to go ahead with this approach you can do something like this:

```
setuserForm([...route.params.paramKey]);
```

EDIT:
After you added

```
route.params.paramKey = {"objeto":"CLMobj_test","fields":["abcs","test"],"type":["Date","Text"]}
```

You can just set

```
setuserForm(JSON.parse(route.params.paramKey).fields)
```

and use map on it

```
{userForm.length > 0 ?
  (userForm.map((item) => <Text key={uuid.v4()}>{item}</Text>):
  (<Text key={uuid.v4()}> Loading ... </Text>)
}
```

Comment: it removed my error but, do you know why it returns me this console.log`["{\"objeto\":\"CLMobj_test\",\"fields\":[\"abcs\",\"test\"],\"type\":[\"Date\",\"Text\"]}"]`

Comment: Updated the answer according to the new details

Comment: I just put the `setuserForm([route.params.paramKey])` and it started returning me that crazy json @DipanshKhandelwal

Comment: you have to add `...`

```setuserForm([...route.params.paramKey])```

Comment: when I add this it gets evne crazier look at the log of `userForm` when I put like this.  (` ["{", "\"", "o", "b", "j", "e", "t", "o", "\"", ":", "\"", "C", "L", "M", "o", "b", "j", "_", "t", "e", "s", "t", "\"", ",", "\"", "f", "i", "e", "l", "d", "s", "\"", ":", "[", "\"", "a", "b", "c", "s", "\"", ",", "\"", "t", "e", "s", "t", "\"", "]", ",", "\"", "t", "y", "p", "e", "\"", ":", "[", "\"", "D", "a", "t", "e", "\"", ",", "\"", "T", "e", "x", "t", "\"", "]", "}"] `)

Comment: since its not a string but a json string. First convert that string to json ```JSON.parse(route.params.paramKey)``` and then use its data from `json.fields` to map and show the data

Comment: I have updated the answer
```setuserForm(JSON.parse(route.params.paramKey).fields)```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239673/discussion-between-dipansh-khandelwal-and-guilherme-cavenaghi).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this code, note that I've changed the "Use Effect" conditon, and JSX also:

```
  const FormScreen = ({route}) => {
  const [userForm, setuserForm] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      setuserForm(JSON.parse(route.params.paramKey));
  },[])
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>COLLECTION :</Text>     
        {!!userForm && userForm.fields.length > 0 ? (       
          userForm.fields.map((item) => (          
            <Text key={uuid.v4()}>{item}</Text>
          ))
        ) : (
          <Text key={uuid.v4()}> Loading ... </Text>
        )}
```

Comment: When I use this, the userForm.length dont works @AmineBENETTAJ

Comment: @GuilhermeCavenaghi Yes, change it for "userForm.fields.length"

Comment: when I put like this it returns me ` userForm.fields.length` is undefined

Comment: @GuilhermeCavenaghi I edited the answer, I changed the UseEffect function and the returned JSX.